# Actualizar los datos de jTable al editar, eliminar o modificar elementos

Tags: java, jtable

mi problema es el siguiente:

-Tengo un jTable en el que muestro objetos tipo Student de una base de datos, tengo tres metodos que funcionan correctamente. Bien, mi problema es que cuando ejecuto un metodo de estos la tabla no se actualiza, si no que duplica la tabla y mete otra con los datos modificados. Adjunto foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que me elimine los datos antiguos y los sustituya con los nuevos?

Tengo un metodo refrescarTaboa() que en principio es el que la modifica cada vez que hay algún cambio, pero como veis me lo duplica. Adjunto codigo:

```
public void refrescarTaboa() {
    String[] columnas = new String[]{"DNI", "NAME", "Surname", "Age"};
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columnas);
    
  
    for (Student stu : loxicaNegocio.getStudentsList()) {
        String[] student = new String[4];
        student[0] = stu.getDNI();
        student[1] = stu.getName();
        student[2] = stu.getSurname();
        student[3] = Integer.toString(stu.getAge());
        dtm.addRow(student);
    }
     jTableStudents.setModel(dtm);
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no se si lo has logrado solucionar hasta ahora, pero para borrar todas las filas una tabla uso

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

de este modo elimina todas las filas de la tabla, se me ocurre que agregues eso en el método  `refrescarTabla()` antes de cargar los registros, esto tendría que eliminar los registros antiguos que están en la tabla y agregarías los registros de la base de datos, en la tabla ya limpia

Comment: Vaya, yo siempre reasignaba le table model a uno nuevo con un nuevo arreglo con los datos. ¿Qué ventajas tiene tu enfoque aparte de tener menos líneas?

Comment: Me añadiendo esa linea de codigo mi programa se ejecuta de igual manera.

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el código del botón editar y también el del método loxicaNegocio.getStudentsList(), el problema debe estar en uno de ellos